# yii2 throw error instead of redirecting to login page

Tags: yii, yii2

I do not want people who guess a url to be automatically redirected to the login page. Instead of the redirect I'd like to throw an error unless of course you are logged in. What is the yii2 way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. In `behaviours` you can add

```
[
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    ...
    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
    }
]
```

as per http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: This is the best solution you can do. Instead of creating new filters, or override beforAction, a filter is already done. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

You can override beforeAction() method in the related Controllers.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if(Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest && !in_array($action->id,['allowed', 'actions', 'here']))
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'Page could not be found.');

    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For further reading on the topic you can check out the Yii2 Docs: [yii\base\Controller beforeAction() details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail)

Comment: Yes, but the point was you can put your custom access control code there. Adding another condition solves your problem. I will adjust the code.